# Having trouble sending form information to server

Tags: angular

I am using Angular framework, and I am still trying to figure things out... I am using Restangular to post

For reference:

```
feedback: Feedback; (feedback class)
feedbackCopy = null; (to be used to check for form entry before posting to server)
feedbackForm = FormGroup;
```

I am working on putting together a form that will take input information, and post it to the server.

```
onSubmit(){
//store form values in feedback object
this.feedback = this.feedbackForm.value;
//log object to console
console.log(this.feedback);
//give feedback info to feedback class to be stored in object
this.feedbackCopy.push(this.feedback);
this.feedbackCopy.save().subscribe(feedback => { this.feedback = feedback; console.log(this.feedback)})
//reset for to empty values
this.feedbackForm.reset({
  firstname: '',
  lastname: '',
  telnum: '',
  email: '',
  agree: false,
  contacttype: 'None',
  message: ''
});
```

}

Above is the code for the Submit function that is supposed to post the information to the server. It stops at the

```
this.feedbackCopy.push(this.feedback);
```

line and says that .push is not a function

```
ERROR TypeError: this.feedbackCopy.push is not a function
at ContactComponent.onSubmit (contact.component.ts:122)
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: like the error says, there is no function like `push` for a `null` value. `push` is for an array ;)

Comment: would I change `feedbackCopy = [ ];` ? I tried doing that and I show error `ERROR TypeError: this.feedbackCopy.push is not a function`

Comment: Yes, declaring it as an empy array would work. If it doesn't work for you, there would be something else going on. Could you reproduce the issue in a stackblitz perhaps?

Comment: OK so it looks like I am able to push it to the array. But now it looks like it is getting caught up at the `.save()` throwing `ERROR TypeError: this.feedbackCopy.save is not a function
    at `

Comment: Well again, there is no `save` function on an array.

Answer (score 0):

1. feedbackCopy needs to be an array for "this.feedbackCopy.push(this.feedback);" to avoid error.
2. feedbackCopy needs to be a ngx-restangular object for 
   "this.feedbackCopy.post()..." to avoid error.

You need to prepare feedbackCopy as a right type (i.e., restangular) before calling onSubmit()